# JTidy Node.findBody() — How to use?

Tags: java, xml, xhtml, tidy, jtidy

I'm trying to do XHTML DOM parsing with JTidy, and it seems to be rather counterintuitive task. In particular, there's a method to parse HTML:

```
Node Tidy.parse(Reader, Writer)
```

And to get the <body /> of that Node, I assume, I should use

```
Node Node.findBody(TagTable)
```

Where should I get an instance of that TagTable? (Constructor is protected, and I haven't found a factory to produce it.)

I use JTidy 8.0-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found there's *much* simpler method to extract the body:

```
tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setXHTML(true);
tidy.setPrintBodyOnly(true);
```

And then use tidy on the Reader-Writer pair.

Simple as it should be.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `parseDOM` method instead, which would give you a `org.w3c.dom.Document` back:

```
Document document = Tidy.parseDOM(reader, writer);
Node body = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);
```