# jTidy - Pretty Printing without Head, Title Tags

Tags: java, pretty-print, jtidy

I am trying to use jTidy to pretty print on a HTML snippet that I have. So far I have done the following.

```
protected String prettyPrintHTML(String rawHTML) {

    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    tidy.setXHTML(true);
    tidy.setIndentContent(true);
    tidy.setPrintBodyOnly(true);
    tidy.setTidyMark(false);

    // Convert HTML to DOM
    Document htmlDOM = tidy.parseDOM(new ByteArrayInputStream(rawHTML.getBytes()), null);

    // Pretty Print
    OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    tidy.pprint(htmlDOM, out);

    return out.toString();
}
```

This works, but the output includes additional content such as <html>, <head>, <title> and <body> tags.

For example, for input <ul><li>sub1</li><li>sub2<ul><li>sub21</li></ul></li></ul> this gives,

```
line 1 column 59 - Warning: inserting missing 'title' element
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        sub1
      </li>
      <li>
        sub2
        <ul>
          <li>
            sub21
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

After skimming through the API, I found the `setPrintBodyOnly` method (which I have used above), but still no luck.

What am I missing here ? I tried Googling but so far all links lead to dead ends.

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question posted in the following link. It has answers which show some alternate ways to achieve the same.

[JTidy Node.findBody() — How to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221277/jtidy-node-findbody-how-to-use)